# eventFilter web3.py in python to get events of locally deployed smart contracts using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, python

I have tried ganache and geth too for contracts deployment locally hosted port # 8545. A function of deployed contract is called from another smart contract (deployed locally on same port)

So its like ContractA func1() -> ContractB func2(p1,p2) { emit event!!! }

ContractA

```
ContractA obj = ContractA(0x034309b0de3af84089cbaf6bb7a5b6f657f9f0e5);
obj.triggerEvent(param1, param2);
```

while ContractB

```
function triggerEvent(uint param1, address param2)
    public {
    emit TotalInv(msg.sender, param1, param2);
 }
```

> Now problem is I am trying to get this event in eventFilter as

```
  current_block = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545')).eth.getBlock('latest')
  event_filter = contractB_instance.eventFilter('TotalInv', {
            'fromBlock': 0,
            'toBlock': current_block['number']
        })
```

Other than this, I have created a simple function returning string in ContractB to check if instance of contractB is correct or not. And its working well, printing that string on console.

Env Details :

Python : 3.6.2

Geth : 1.8.15-stable-89451f7c

Truffle : 4.1.14

Windows 10

Web3.py : 4.6.0

Ganache : 1.1.0

Comment: Could you link to the documentation for `eventFilter`? I can't find it [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html). What is `self.relayer`? It looks like you're passing a dictionary to `toBlock`. You probably want to just pass the string `"latest"` or the `number` member of the return value of `getBlock`.

Comment: Please say it once again: did you actually try deploying both contracts in a private blockchain running on `geth`, not in Truffle's development network, and then subscribing to events?

Comment: Sorry for being too much late, 
@smarx eventFilter is provided in PyDoc you can search [here](http://pydoc.net/web3/4.0.0b5/web3.contract/). Then "self.relayer" that was actual name of contractB_instance. About 'getBlock', you were right so I changed this to current_block['number']. But still no difference

Comment: @Utgarda yes I have deployed both contracts in private blockchain GETH and Ganache too using Web3. Even after subscribing to the events I am not getting any event triggered.